# asp.net core: is there a way to branch a request to the root path using app.Map() in the pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have tried the following, which kind of works, but it seems to catch all requests.

```
 app.Map("", appbuilder =>
 {
 }
```

For example, if there is a request to the exact path of `https://localhost:5001/`, I want to be able to branch on that exact match?

I am stuck after trying to research ways to do this, but haven't found a solid answer.

Comment: Have a look for this discussion:https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/683, 
 app.Map is using like StartsWith(string.Empty) to match route string,so I think[@Kirk Larkin's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63962359/12884742) is a good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MapWhen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.mapwhenextensions.mapwhen) works for this. Here's an example:

```
app.MapWhen(
    ctx => ctx.Request.Path == "/",
    appBuilder =>
    {
        
    });
```

The first argument passed into `MapWhen` is a predicate used to determine whether or not to branch the pipeline.